# Variable selection for multiple linear regression: lasso, stepwise or something else?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, feature-selection, lasso, likert

I have to do an analysis in order to find the correlation between an agent questionnaire and a usability questionnaire both of which are using Likert scales. I only have 90 samples and 25 predictors so I need to reduce them; otherwise I'm overfitting my model, right? I was wondering what type of regression I should do. I read an example in a book about statistical methods for user experience that uses stepwise but a couple of friends suggested $L_1$ or LASSO.

Comment: A multiple-regression model isn't going to help you find a correlation between two things. Do you mean "association"?

Comment: I want to see which of the 25 IVs (which are questions of a questionnaire using 5 point Likert scale) consist the best model that explain the mean Usability score.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific than "best", because there are various competing notions of model quality. For example, the fit of the model will necessarily be maximized by including all the IVs, but its predictive accuracy can be hurt by overfitting.

Comment: I guess I mean the least biased model. 25 are definitely going to overfit the model. I need to reduce the predictors down to approx. 6. Also I was doing linear multiple regression but I read that for likert scales maybe i should use Ordered Logistic Regression.

Comment: Since you have 25 predictors and 90 samples, you can even exhaustively search (e.g. Leaps and Bounds method) through all combinations $2^{25}$ and find the one with lowest estimated error.

Comment: @DaKor If your question is "How do I maximize fit of a linear regression model with 6 predictors?", the answer is just "try all (25 choose 6) = 177,100 models and see which one has the least MSE". But that seems like a somewhat silly notion of "best".

Comment: I should mention at this point that I don't have a theoretical reason to pick one over the other when selecting predictors that's why based on the rule of thumb i should have 10-15 samples per predictor thus around 6.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? Do you need a model that will do best in terms of out-of-sample forecasting (where best needs to be defined by a loss function, such as mean squared forecast error)? Or are you trying to find out which variables truly belong to a hypothesized "true" model? Or yet something else? Because each goal will have a different corresponding "best" model.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit new to all this. I guess I want to see how much of the Usability can be explained by the agent and consequently which traits of the agent affect the usability the most.

Comment: @RichardHardy Out-of-sample forecasting that would be.

Comment: Between subset selection and lasso, I would go for lasso. You could also try elastic net.

Comment: @RichardHardy I read about elastic net as well which is something between ridge and lasso if not mistaken. Question is: Can I do LASSO or elastic net on SPSS?

Comment: @RichardHardy What if I want to find out which variables truly belong to a hypothesized "true" model?

Comment: That is a different task. Adaptive lasso is suited for that. And I don't work with SPSS, so I don't know if lasso is available there.